# How to execute ctrl+c or copy commad using javascript or jquery on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, copy

Is it possible to execute copy command using click EVENT?

I have some text selected and I want this text to be copied on `onClick` event, so that I am able to past this text to another page with out using right click or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text.

Answer (score 2):

```
function copyText(){
    var txt = '';
     if (window.getSelection)
        txt = window.getSelection();
    else if (document.getSelection)
        txt = document.getSelection();
    else return;
    document.getElementById("a").value=txt;
    allCopied =document.getElementById("a").createTextRange();
    allCopied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");

   allCopied.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

but for security reasons most browsers do not allow to modify the **clipboard(** except  **Internet explorer)**.

Comment: I think instead of "document.getElementById("a").value="txt";" you meant "document.getElementById("a").value=txt;" but otherwise, this helped me a ton. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
<span onclick="copyText(this)" >Text1</span>, <span onclick="copyText(this)" >Text2</span>
<br>
<input name="myField"></input>
```

JavaScript

```
function copyText(element) {
document.myForm.myField.value = element.innerHTML;
}
```

Copy to Clip Board   Ctrl+C

```
$("#text1").click(function(){
var holdtext = $("#clipboard").innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [getselection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection) to get selected text inside a browser window