# Copy To Clipboard Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

See answer below.

Also see: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) for an older approach.

---

> Original question:

I want to be able to copy a table-cells value whenever a user clicks.
I've tried this:

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var selectTableCells = document.querySelector('td');

    selectTableCells.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log("You copied: ", selectTableCells);
        copyToClipboard(selectTableCells.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 160px;
}
td {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" class="responsive" style="width:1000px;">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Field Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="cell1">Click me to copy!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<input type="text" style="height:50px;width:300px;" placeholder="For proof of concept. Try to paste here">
```

Comment: Any thing you have tried.

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you have tried with different stuffs, I'm just asking you to update your respective stuff which you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: oh. ok. 
 [link](http://zeroclipboard.org/)
But, it's not what i want. i just want the user to press the cell (the value) and it will be copied.

Comment: Hey there. I've included the content of your comment to the question and slightly reformated your question. Try and add relevant information directly into your question instead of in a comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer from the future (2020):

---

*There is now a Clipboard API*

This snippet fetches the text from the clipboard and appends it to the first element found with the class editor. Since `readText()` (and `read()`, for that matter) returns an empty string if the clipboard isn't text, this code is safe.

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
    clipText => document.querySelector(".editor").innerText += clipText);
```

## Methods:

Note: **All methods return a promise**

### read()

```
var getClipboardData = navigator.clipboard.read();
```

The `read()`  method of the Clipboard interface requests a copy of the clipboard's contents, returns a Promise.  Unlike `readText()`, the `read()` method can return arbitrary data, such as **images**. This method can also return text.

### readText()

```
var getClipboardText = navigator.clipboard.readText();
```

Returns an empty string if the clipboard is empty, does not contain text, or does not include a textual representation among the `DataTransfer` objects representing the clipboard's contents.

### write()

```
var setClipboardData = navigator.clipboard.write(data);
```

The promise is rejected if the clipboard is unable to complete the clipboard access.

### writeText()

```
var setClipboardText = navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClipText);
```

The promise is rejected if the caller does not have permission to write to the clipboard.

---

## Interfaces:

`Clipboard Secure context`

Provides an interface for reading and writing text and data to or from the system clipboard. The specification refers to this as the 'Async Clipboard API.'

`ClipboardEvent Secure context`

Represents events providing information related to modification of the clipboard, that is cut, copy, and paste events. The specification refers to this as the 'Clipboard Event API'.

`ClipboardItem Secure context`

Represents a single item format, used when reading or writing data.

---

For more info, see [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

Comment: For more information on this API, read the [article](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/) with examples for all operations.

Answer (score -1):

try this attribute contenteditable="true" and try following this link to copy your clipboard contents,
[execute ctrl + c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530738/how-to-execute-ctrlc-or-copy-commad-using-javascript-or-jquery-on-button-click)