# How do I NOT copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, selection, x11, textselection

I have suddenly in recent months repeatedly suffered FF (last few??? versions) web pages overwriting my X primary selection ON THEIR OWN. This is an enormous vulnerability, as I usually paste with middle mouse button. If FF gets in after my drag-to-select in any app, I'm sometimes shocked to paste remote multi-line content into the Shell :-(

- The horrible NetSkope https-mitm-proxy error page (for a small static message a huge JS, that reloads every few seconds) selects the page content on every reload. I thus conscientiously close it ASAP, if I accidentally get it.
- I also sometimes get generic (cookie bla bla or some such IIRC) text from some page that I haven't identified (among my ton of open tabs).
- Now while writing this, got it twice from SO: when clicking "Ask question" from another Q, I got the `<footer>` of the page I came from become my selection. While playing around, suddenly the instructions that were initially under the Q-form became my selection.

I have studied these Qs, which repeat a gazillion times the same 2 ways to achieve this. They always say a mouse click is necessary, but in my above cases it happens when I'm not even in FF! I WANT THIS TO NEVER HAPPEN!

[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript),
[Copy To Clipboard Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187130/copy-to-clipboard-javascript)

Comment: You'll need to install a script execution plugin, like tampermonkey, and write code which prevents a copy/paste listener?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1595994/dont-let-websites-overwrite-clipboard-in-firefox-without-explicitly-giving-perm

Comment: Thanks, @KonradLinkowski! Those settings in the superuser thread sound very promising! If that's the solution, the FF devs (or probably marketing) must be out of their minds to have such defaults. This merits a critical CVE!